# unsigned long long behaving odd in C

Tags: c, variables, undefined-behavior, unsigned-long-long-int

I stumbled across a very odd issue when running a program compiled for MIPS. 
The following snippet of code is to get the time epoch and store it in microsecond-precision in an `unsigned long long` variable.

The variable is capable of storing 8 bytes which I checked with `sizeof(unsigned long long)`.

This code prints out weirdly:

```
unsigned long long microtime=0;
struct timeval time_camera = { .tv_sec=0, .tv_usec=0 };
gettimeofday(&time_camera,NULL);
microtime = time_camera.tv_sec * 1000000 + time_camera.tv_usec;
printf("Times is now %llu , time since epoch in seconds is: %lu\n", microtime, time_camera.tv_sec);
```

It gives me the following output:

```
>> Times is now 484305845 , time since epoch in seconds is: 1357751315
```

However, when I break the calculation into different lines, it works! :

```
unsigned long long microtime=0;
struct timeval time_camera = { .tv_sec=0, .tv_usec=0 };
gettimeofday(&time_camera,NULL);
microtime = time_camera.tv_sec;
microtime = microtime * 1000000;
microtime = microtime  + time_camera.tv_usec;
printf("Times is now %llu , time since epoch in seconds is: %lu\n", microtime, time_camera.tv_sec);
```

Output is:

```
Times is now 1357751437422143 , time since epoch in seconds is: 1357751437
```

Now is it just a coincidence that this works ? e.g have I corrupted memory or actually exceeded it somewhere? Perhaps it's the MIPS compilator? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
microtime = time_camera.tv_sec * 1000000 + time_camera.tv_usec;
```

`tv_sec` is a smaller integer type (`time_t`, probably `int` or `long`), so

```
time_camera.tv_sec * 1000000
```

overflows. Use a suffix to give the constant the appropriate type

```
time_camera.tv_sec * 1000000ULL
```

In

```
microtime = time_camera.tv_sec;
microtime = microtime * 1000000;
```

the multiplication is performed at `unsigned long long`, since one operand (`microtime`) already has that type, so the other is converted to that.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you just have `size_t` math going on before you assign to your `unsigned long long`. try putting `ULL` after your constants.

Another way to do it is `(unsigned long long) 1000000`. As long as you have this on at least one of your operands in a multiplication, you can be assured the result will be the higher precedence type. The implicit type conversion precedence rules are (in order of highest to lowest):

`long double` => `double` => `float` => `unsigned long long` => `long long` => `unsigned long` => `long` => `unsigned int` => `int`

Comment: Thank you for posting the precedence rules!